# How can make a function return a value defined by a subclass? C++

Tags: c++

I have instances which are defined by a Super class but also by a subclass. The called function is the one in the Super class as this is thesame for all my instances. The result of this function however should be defined by the subclass they are in. This is a simplified example:

```
class superClass{ 
public:
    //the "called" function, should not create a value on its own (empty)
    vector<int>vec(){...}       
}

class subClass1:public superClass{
public:
    //should set vector to the desired value when it is of type SubClass1
    vector<int>vec(){...}   
} 

class subClass2:public superClass{
public:
    //should set vector to the desired value when it is of type SubClass2
    vector<int>vec(){...}   
} 


...
```

I have no idea how to actually link these function calls. The function runs correctly since whenever i assign a value directly in the superClass this can be printed. If i try it with the subClass there is an error (because of trying to print an item that does not exist).

Any help on how this can be done would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for [virtual functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual)?

Comment: Well, to be honest i don't know. I got this file from my teacher and am supposed to work it all out in some way. There is already a virtual function in here but i have no idea how this works.

Comment: all i know is that the methods to be added should be of the form: vector<int>vec(){...}

Comment: You should begin by reading about virtual functions. If it doesn't work out, edit your question with more information to make it clearer what you are trying to do and why virtual functions didn't work out as a solution. Perhaps an example to illustrate how you intend to use `subClass1` and `subClass2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`virtual` function is what you're looking for.

Declare the function in the super class with a `virtual` prefix, then whenever you call that function, the overload that will be actually called will be dependent on the type of the actual object.

Answer (score 0):

So, something like :

```
class SuperClass
{ 
    public:
        virtual vector<int> vec() = 0;
};

class SubClass1 : public SuperClass
{
    public:
        virtual vector<int> vec()
        {
            vector<int> v;
            ...
            return v;
        }
};

class SubClass2 : public SuperClass
{
    public:
        virtual vector<int> vec()
        {
            vector<int> v;
            ...
            return v;
        }
};
```

Or, if SuperClass is not abstract, implement it as :

```
class SuperClass
{ 
    public:
        virtual vector<int> vec()
        {
            vector<int> v;
            return v;
        }
};
```